# django: cannot import settings, cannot login to admin, cannot change admin password

Tags: django, settings

It seems that I am completely lost here. Yesterday I noticed that I cannot login to the admin panel (don't use it much, so it's been some weeks since last login). I thought that I might have changed the admin password and now I can't remember it (though I doubt it).

I tried django-admin.py changepassword (using django 1.2.1) but it said that 'changepassword' is unknown command (I have all the necessary imports in my settings.py. Admin interface used to work ok).

Then I gave a django-admin.py validate. Then the hell begun. django-admin.py validate gave me this error: Error: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.

I then gave a set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings

and then again a django-admin.py validate

This is what I get now: Error: Could not import settings 'myproject.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named myproject.settings

and now I am lost. I tried django console and sys.path.append('c:\workspace') or sys.append('c:\workspace\myproject') but still get the same errors.

I use windows 7 and my project dir is c:\workspace. I don't use a PYTHONPATH variable (although I tried setting it temporarily to C:\workspace but I still get the same error). I don't use Apache, just the django development server.

What am I doing wrong? My web page works fine. I think that the fact that I can't login as admin is related to the previous import error, no?

PS: I also tried this: http://coderseye.com/2007/howto-reset-the-admin-password-in-django.html but still I couldn't change admin password for some reason. Although I could create another admin user (with which I couldn't login).

-EDIT- I forgot to mention that I use postgresql.

Answer (score 2):

django-admin.py  doesnot have  `changepassword` option;

python manage.py does

Comment: I read it here. That is why I tried it. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-changepassword

Comment: However I tried manage.py changepassword and createsuperuser. Both of them worked. Still I can't login to admin panel or my web page with admin users.  :-(

Comment: In django-admin.py ,there are two paramters:--settings=SETTINGS  and --pythonpath=PYTHONPATH , see the help doc of them ,this can explain that in your question.

Comment: and you use postgre,if you username and password is matched,check your project`s admin setting